# Matplotlib equivalent to ggplot geom_ribbon?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I would like to reproduce the ggplot style of showing a confidence interval around a value with a ribbon, like geom_ribbon or geom_smooth.

I tried calculating the confidence interval separately and plotting with `fill_between()` which is close but doesn't seem exactly right.  How can the x axis be the style that comes from `plot_date()` while using `fill_between()`?  What about smoothing of the ribbon?

Example output:

[image]
[image]

The ggplot code looks like this (several found examples):

```
qplot(wt, mpg, data=mtcars, colour=factor(cyl)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl), data=grid, stat="identity")

ggplot(answers.overall, aes(Date, Answers)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason why you can't use **ggplot** for Python? Because that would really simplify things a lot:

```
import ggplot as gg

mtcars = gg.mtcars
gg.qplot(mtcars.wt, mtcars.mpg) + gg.geom_smooth(color="blue")
```

Comment: I just wasn't aware that it exists :)  Thanks!

Comment: ggplot I think doesn't work with the latest pandas now

Comment: @IlayaRajaS Thanks for the info. Do you know how long it has been since **ggplot** stopped working? As an aside, one reason I moved away from Python for Data Analysis is because it seemed like every time I'd update my packages something would break.

Comment: There is a fix for that ggplot issue, albeit a manual one:
https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/issues/662#issuecomment-484138308